# Android Library Projects in Eclipse - Jar files doesn't show up in the r14 sdk tools

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library

I have updated my SDK tools to r14. In [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/changes-to-library-projects-in-android.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20blogspot/hsDu%20%28Android%20Developers%20Blog%29) link it is told that the library projects will show up as `jar` files in the projects which uses the library project. But the `jar` files are not showing up and the `<libraryproject>_src` folder is still visible. While migrating to r14 from previous version is there any specific step/settings that I need to follow/change so that the library projects are included as jar files? Should I first export the library project as `jar` file and then include it? I would like to know if anyone has done this and how they have done it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work.

I rebuilt the library project and a `<libraryproject>.jar` appeared in the `bin` folder. Then I removed the reference from the project which uses the `<libraryproject>` and added it in the same way as before.

`Project properties -> Android ->` in the Library section I added the reference to the `<libraryproject>` and it created a `Library Projects` in the current project containing the `<libraryproject>.jar` file.

Fortunately, there was no switch case statements involving the resouce IDs in my entire library projects. For those of you who is not able to get it to work right away, I would suggest them to go through the link I have posted in the Question.

Comment: I wasted a ton of time on this and solved by removing the library project, clicking apply (getting more errors) then add the library project back, click apply